# how can I rescale data following a bernoulli distribution

Tags: python, statistics, range, standardized, feature-scaling

I have read various articles talking about standardization and normalization but none of the offers a concrete example on how to rescale data using their formulas.

I would like to transform data as follows;
given ***data = [x1...xn]***
**rescale(data,n)** should  it rescale it to n whilst retaining **distribution** for example

```
eg_1 = np.array([1]) -->rescale(eg, 2) -->[0.5, 0.5]

eg_2  = np.array([1,1]) -->rescale(eg_2, 4) -->[0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5]

eg3 = np.array([0,1]) --> rescale(eg_3,4) --> [0,0,0.5,0.5]
```

If possible, I would also like for the inverse to be true, for example

```
inv_eg1 = np.array([0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5]) --->inv_rescale(inv_eg1,2) --> [1,1]
```

My initial attempt was simply the formula, (sum of variables in the array/total length of array) * range no. of desired range = value at range no position.
but unfortunately, it not retain the distribution.

The purpose is, I want to apply various kernels and matrices of different shapes but i do not want to use padding.

Please help

Comment: Is n always even for your question?

Comment: it could be even or odd as specified by the user

Comment: so could you give me an example on how you would make [0,1]  to n=5 distribution?

Comment: more generally, how would [0,1,1] be rescaled to n=5? As in, what would be the output?

Comment: in this case it would be [0,1,1] would turn into [0,0.25,0.25,0.5,1] if the values retain the distribution, not very sure